# Laravel 5.5 - Notifications are not being queued?

Tags: laravel-5.5, laravel-queue, laravel-notification

I have the following notification class:

```
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;

class ConfirmEmailNotification extends Notification implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Queueable;

    public function __construct()
    {
       //
    }

    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['mail'];
    }

    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        $user = $notifiable;
        $url = url('/register/confirm/'. $user->confirmation_token);

        return (new MailMessage)
           ->subject('Confirm Email')
           ->markdown('emails.confirm', ['user' => $user, 'url' => $url]);

    }

    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
     }
}
```

In my controller I have the following:

```
$when = now()->addSeconds(30);
$user->notify((new ConfirmEmailNotification())->delay($when));
```

But nothing is getting added to the queue table - the emails is being fired instantly?

I configured the queue as follows.

In my env file:

```
QUEUE_DRIVER=database
```

In my config/queue.php I have renamed the table as follows:

```
'database' => [
        'driver' => 'database',
        'table' => 'queued_jobs',
        'queue' => 'default',
        'retry_after' => 90,
 ],
```

Run the following:

```
php artisan queue:table

php artisan migrate

php artisan queue:work
```

I've tried `php artisan config:clear` but no difference.

Any ideas chaps?

Answer (score 4):

Fixed by restarting `php artisan serve`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i forgot to update the ***QUEUE_CONNECTION*** property in ***.env*** file.

After updating the ***QUEUE_CONNECTION*** to ***database*** it worked as intended.